Python3.10.14: ImportError: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I have multiple versions of Python installed on my system:

Python3.12
Python3.11
Python3.10

I am able to do 'import ssl' in Python 3.12 and 3.11, but I get the following error in Python3.10:
[user@computer ~]$ python3.10
Python 3.10.14 (main, Jun 21 2024, 12:39:03) [GCC 11.4.1 20231218 (Red Hat 11.4.1-3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 99, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>> exit()


Not sure if this info helps but I am using Ansible to do these installs on Rocky Linux.
For OpenSSL, Python3.11 and Python3.12, I am doing a DNF install
---
- name: Installing Packages via DNF
  ansible.builtin.dnf:
    name:
      - openssl
      - python3.11
      - python3.11-pip
      - python3.12
      - python3.12-pip
    state: present
...

As for Python3.10.14, I am installing it manually
---
- name: Create Directory /usr/bin/
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /usr/bin/
    state: directory

- name: Unarchive Python 3.10.14 Tar File into /usr/bin
  ansible.builtin.unarchive:
    src: 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.14/Python-3.10.14.tar.xz'
    dest: /usr/bin/
    remote_src: yes

- name: Configure Python 3.10.14
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd:  'cd /usr/bin/Python-3.10.14/; ./configure --enable-optimizations'

- name: Install Python 3.10.14 via Make
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: 'cd /usr/bin/Python-3.10.14/; make -j 2 ; nproc ; make altinstall ;'
...


Possibly because the version of libssl expected by the 3.10 is not the one you have on by installing openssl.

What is your exact version of Rocky Linux?

Rocky Linux version is 9.3

Update DNF Package List
sudo dnf update -y

Install Required Dependencies
First, you will need to install some dependencies required to compile Python 3.10.14
# Python 3.10.14 Dependencies
sudo dnf install -y \
wget \
tk-devel \
xz-devel \
zlib-devel \
openssl-devel \
sqlite-devel \
libffi-devel \
readline-devel \
libnsl2 \
libffi-devel \
bzip2-devel \
pip \

# Development Tools Mandatory
dnf groupinstall "Development Tools" -y

Download Python
cd /usr/local/bin
wget install https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.14/Python-3.10.14.tar.xz

Extract the the Python Tar File
tar -xvf Python-3.10.14.tar.xz

Configure
The configure script is responsible for getting ready to build the software on your specific system. It makes sure all of the dependencies for the rest of the build and install process are available, and finds out whatever it needs to know to use those dependencies.
Unix programs are often written in C, so we’ll usually need a C compiler to build them. In these cases the configure script will establish that your system does indeed have a C compiler, and find out what it’s called and where to find it.
cd /usr/local/bin/Python-3.10.14
./configure --with-openssl=/usr --enable-optimizations

NOTE: The key here is to point --with-openssl to the /usr directory and not /usr/lib/ssl or /usr/bin/ssl
Build the Install using Make
Once configure has done its job, we can invoke make to build the software. This runs a series of tasks defined in a Makefile to build the finished program from its source code.
The tarball you download usually doesn’t include a finished Makefile. Instead it comes with a template called Makefile.in and the configure script produces a customised Makefile specific to your system.
make -j 2

Install Python using Make Altinstall
Now that the software is built and ready to run, the files can be copied to their final destinations. The make install command will copy the built program, and its libraries and documentation, to the correct locations.
This usually means that the program’s binary will be copied to a directory on your PATH, the program’s manual page will be copied to a directory on your MANPATH, and any other files it depends on will be safely stored in the appropriate place.
Since the install step is also defined in the Makefile, where the software is installed can change based on options passed to the configure script, or things the configure script discovered about your system.
Depending on where the software is being installed, you might need escalated permissions for this step so you can copy files to system directories. Using sudo will often do the trick.
make test
make altinstall

Verification
/usr/local/bin/python3.10 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"


How will this fix errors such as ImportError: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory when the question is about building on Rocky Linux v9.3, which uses OpenSSL 3.0.7?  There still won't be a libssl.so.1.1 that the version of Python being built in the question requires.

@AndrewHenle - Python3.10 requires OpenSSL 1.1.1 or newer, so OpenSSL 3.0.7 is compatible here. Source: https://peps.python.org/pep-0644/
If the SSL version must be 1.1.1 for whatever reason, it can be manually installed. You would then configure the build for Python3.10 again and change the -with-openssl to point to that directory.
